# WIX-MSI: Password enabled uninstallation failing if msiexec is killed

Tags: wix, password-protection, custom-action, windows-installer, wix3.11

We have a wix msi project and custom action dll. While uninstallation, it launches custom action to ask the user for the password and validate the password to allow uninstallation.

**Custom Action**:

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_Uninstall"
              BinaryKey="BIN"
              DllEntry="ValidatePassword"
              Execute="immediate"
              Impersonate="yes"
              Return="check" />
```

**Custom Action Call**:

```
<Custom Action="CA_ProtectUninstall" After="InstallInitialize">
<![CDATA[Uninstalling = "true"]]>
</Custom>
```

Custom action Internally creates MFC dialog and validates the password.
**Part of Custom Action**:

```
    UINT er = ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;

    // launch MFC dialog and validates password
    int ret = dlg.DoModal(hParent);

    er = ret == IDOK ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT;
    return WcaFinalize(er);
```

**Problem:**
This custom action is working fine and properly validates the password. Whenever uninstall is started, windows start process msiexec.exe in users context. Now there are 2 msiexec.exe processes, 1 in the system and another in user context.
While uninstallation, When password dialog is shown, if the user kills msiexec process from user context, password dialog gets closed and uninstall succeeds without validating the password.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?. Please feel free to suggest any better option to handle password protected uninstallation.

**Uninstall logs for custom action**:

```
MSI (s) (B4:A8) [16:21:20:873]: Doing action: CA_Uninstall
MSI (s) (B4:A8) [16:21:20:873]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 16:21:20: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (B4:90) [16:21:20:885]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI4913.tmp, Entrypoint: ValidatePassword
Action start 16:21:20: CA_Uninstall.
MSI (s) (B4:90) [16:21:29:686]: Leaked MSIHANDLE (252) of type 790541 for thread 20604
MSI (s) (B4:90) [16:21:29:686]: Note: 1: 2769 2: CA_Uninstall 3: 1 
MSI (s) (B4:90) [16:21:29:686]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (B4:90) [16:21:29:686]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2769 
ValidatePassword:  ValidatePassword: UILevel=3
DEBUG: Error 2769:  Custom Action CA_Uninstall did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2769. The arguments are: CA_Uninstall, 1,
```

Comment: Can we ask why you need to validate the password before uninstalling? GUI from uninstall is bad enough, GUI that is not suppressible for silent mode uninstallation is very bad. By the way, if you use MFC in setups, at least statically link. Avoid any GUI in the setup if you can is the golden rule.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Yes, I understand and agree with you. The requirement is to allow uninstall only if the password is provided. I know there can be other ways to remove program but that we are not worried as of now. MFC is statically linked.

Comment: Have to tell you that this design sort of invites a lot of deployment problems. For example major upgrades - they entail uninstall and reinstall in and of itself technically (which might be unexpected and might hang if you don't condition that dialog properly to not show up). We really need to know WHY you have to provide a password for the uninstall before sane advice can be given. I suspect this could have something to do with a very vulnerable technical detail that will trigger massive deployment problems (cipher?) - or it could be a trifle - we do not know until we understand.

Comment: @Nimish A password protected uninstallation by means of MSI is *very* vulnerable. It can be overriden by a lot of ways so I'd recommend you to invent some other method of protection.